# how to create a generic code to called from every method in web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a method, which i need to call from every web method in a web service.

I need to call this method just to check a particular value from DB is 1 or 0

i have implemented it already by adding redundant ADO.NET code in every method which would call the DB to fetch the value

Is there a better way of doing this and avoiding redundant code..

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply write a method for this and call in every web method?

Comment: You could move this code to a behavior (if you're using `WCF`)

Comment: Can i move this code into a class and make it singleton